# Progress on group languages characterizations

Tags: gr.group-theory, formal-languages, semigroups-and-monoids

**Def.** A group language is a recognizable language whose syntactic monoid is a group.

**q1.** Is it known a "nice" combinatorial characterization of group languages ?

**q1.1.** If no, is it well understood why it is so? Is there recent progress on this ?

**q2.** Let F be a proper family of group languages (for example, abelian groups, etc...)
Do there exist notable instances of F such that a nice combinatorial characterization of F-languages arise ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it is deemed impossible to describe group languages completely since this involves understanding the word problem for each finite simple group for any generating set.

Nice descriptions are known for subclasses like p-groups, nilpotent groups, supersolvable groups and solvable groups.  p-groups are done in Eilenberg's book. Nilpotent groups follow from p-groups but Therien refined this to nilpotent groups of class c. Straubing did solvable groups. Supersolvable groups was published by Pin and collaborators.

Comment: @benjamin-steinberg You should add the easiest case, commutative groups.

Comment: Commutative groups are of course the easiest case using the structure Thm of finite abelian groups.